# Program flow on recursion with strings and ints

Tags: java, string, recursion

I don't understand how this works.  I know basic factoral recursion, but this is of a mixed type.  Could someone explain step by step on what's going on with the output based on this exact code snippet?  Even just a few of the first values (commented at the end of the code)?

## Thanks :)

```
public class recursion1st
{
    public static String recFun(int x)
    {
        if (x <= 0) return "/";
        return recFun(x-3) + x + recFun(x-2) + x;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(recFun(8));
    }
}
//Produces '/2/25/3/1/1358/3/1/136/1/14/2/2468 '(?)
```

Comment: Whenever you use `+` with a `String`, Java performs String concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

In the main function, it is calling *recFun()* to print the data. In that function, which is recursive, the first *if* condition is to break out of recursion, when that condition is met (when x is negative or equal to zero).
Else it will return a string, in turn again calling itself.

Here, in the first return, it calls recFun(5) and and recFun(6) and likewise, if you analyse step by step, the cycle continues till the break condition is met. Basically the return statement is concatenation of strings, and it separates the data by placing "/" on breaking out of recursion.

**EDIT:**
Value returned by return statement is

```
 rec(5)+8+rec(6)+8......(1)
```

where

```
rec(5) returns rec(2)+5+rec(3)+5......(2)
```

and

```
rec(6) returns rec(3)+6+rec(4)+6.......(3)
```

where

```
rec(3) returns "/"+3+rec(1)+3.......(4)
```

and

```
rec(4) returns rec(1)+4+rec(2)+4.....(5)
```

and

```
rec(2) returns "/" +2 +"/"+2.....(6)
```

and

```
rec(1) returns "/"+1+"/"+1 .......(7)
```

Substitute (7) and (6) in (5)

Substitute (7) in (4)

Substitute (4) and (5) in (3)

Substitute (4) and (6) in (2)

and substitute (2) and (3) in (1)

You will need a sheet for this. Try and work it out using this. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

3| function taking an int argument

5| this is your base case, return "/" if...

6| this is your recursion, call recFun(x-3) + x /*this is your current value */ recFun(x-2) + x. basically this is going to go until you're x reaches 0 or less. Note the right root recursive call will go through more recursions before it hits the base case because it is passing x - 2 everytime instead of x-3. Also realize this statement calls recursively twice.

Make a chart on a big piece of paper and map out passing 8 in:

8

root
return recFun(5) + 8 + recFun(6) + 8

1st branch
return recFun(2) + 5 + recFun(3) + 8

2nd branch
return recFun(3) + 6 + recFun(4) + 6
.......................
Keep going it will become clear.

Answer (score 0):

take a paper and write down step by step what the function does:

```
                                     recFun(5)                    
                                        | 
                       recFun(2)   +    5   +    recFun(3)+5     
                         |                          |
              recFun(-1)+2+recFun(0)+2    recFun(0)+3+recFun(1)+3 
                   |           |             |           |
                  "/"         "/"           "/" recFun(-2)+1+recFun(-1)+1
                                                   |            |
                                                  "/"          "/"
```

**1** call recFun with 5

**2** 5 leads to recFun with 2  &  recFun with 3

**3** 2 leads to recFun with -1 &  recFun with 0 , 3 leads to recFun with 0 & recFun with 1

**4** -1 leads to "/", 0 leads to "/", 0 leads to "/", 1 leads to recFun with -2 & recFun(-1)

**5** -2 leads to "/", -1 leads to "/"

Until every singe call is finished executing (until the x <= 0 and a "/" is returned) no call made before will return anything. The function starts returning Strings from the end of that chain of calls (in this pyramid: bottom to top and from right to left)

```
                  / 1 / 1
    / 2 / 2   / 3         3
            5               5
->  / 2 / 2 5 / 3 / 1 / 1 3 5
```

I know, recursion is confusing. The only thing that helps me is: first make every last call of the recursive function and only when the last call returns anything then roll back. Sorry if this isn't any more precise :)

Comment: Thanks GameDroids, it's all clear to me now :)  It is confusing, but you got to leave space to work it out.  I tried a number of 'pyramid' diagrams (different returns, values etc), and they all check out with this method.  Thanks again.